# How can I build a snap package that runs executable jar?

Tags: ubuntu, javafx, executable-jar, snapcraft

I have an executable jar program. It's an JavaFX program. It runs great on OpenJDK 8 and higher. I want to publish it as a snap package in Ubuntu's developer portal. I have it currently packaged as a deb file, however, Ubuntu doesn't accept those. I need to submit it as a snap package.

That's my current hurdle. I am completely new to Snapcraft. I read the documentation at 
http://snapcraft.io It gave a good overview on the terminal commands and the theory behind snap packages.

I still can't seem to package my program (code my snapcraft.yaml) correctly. All I need is the openjdk-8-jre dependency included and my executable jar. The deb package I created installs perfectly and creates a desktop file with an icon so that people could run it from the menu. Is there a way to include this in the snap package?

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1):

In the [Snappy Playpen](https://github.com/ubuntu/snappy-playpen) we collect good examples of snaps. Here a few a which which might help:

- OpenJDK demo: https://github.com/ubuntu/snappy-playpen/tree/master/openjdk-demo
- jtiledownloader: https://github.com/ubuntu/snappy-playpen/tree/master/jtiledownloader
- wallpaperdownloader: https://github.com/ubuntu/snappy-playpen/tree/master/wallpaperdownloader

Comment: I tried to use the openjdk-demo as a template. The openjdk-demo files won't compile in snapcraft. I get this when trying to build: "Snapcraft: snapping ~/snappy-playpen/openjdk-demo/snapcraft.yaml

Snapcraft: Something went wrong.

Snapcraft returned with : Issues while validating snapcraft.yaml: Additional properties are not allowed ('confinement' was unexpected) "

Comment: Which version of snapcraft are you using?

Comment: It's Snapcraft version 2.8.4

Comment: Can you ensure you have the latest updates installed? Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and Ubuntu 16.10 are already up at snapcraft 2.18.1.